# can not enter conda download page

Tags: conda, miniconda

I want to download miniconda as usual, but somehow the download page is crashed:

https://conda.io/miniconda.html

Does anyone know what happened?

It shows:

```
\          SORRY            /
 \                         /
  \    This page does     /
   ]   not exist yet.    [    ,'|
   ]                     [   /  |
   ]___               ___[ ,'   |
   ]  ]\             /[  [ |:   |
   ]  ] \           / [  [ |:   |
   ]  ]  ]         [  [  [ |:   |
   ]  ]  ]__     __[  [  [ |:   |
   ]  ]  ] ]\ _ /[ [  [  [ |:   |
   ]  ]  ] ] (#) [ [  [  [ :===='
   ]  ]  ]_].nHn.[_[  [  [
   ]  ]  ]  HHHHH. [  [  [
   ]  ] /   `HH("N  \ [  [
   ]__]/     HHH  "  \[__[
   ]         NNN         [
   ]         N/"         [
   ]         N H         [
  /          N            \
 /           q,            \
/                           \
```

Comment: Hi. It looks like all of the conda.io links are broken at the moment. This is probably a transient problem. The Miniconda files can be found in the Anaconda repo site: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/

Comment: I see, thank you!!